# Not getting the expected output when 100 is used for the distance / shift

Tags: python, encryption

inputs/outputs are as follows:
set 1: 
"abcde" "128"
expected output/Actual output
"abcde"          /     "abcde"

set 2:
"abcde" "100"
expected output/ actual output
"EFGHI"        /   "«¬­®¯"

set 3:
"Hello World" "3"
expected output / actual output
"Khoor#Zruog"   / "Khoor#Zruog"

Sets 1 & 3 return correctly but 2 does not. I think it has something to do with the character sets im trying to use but i cant figure out how to fix it

```
plainText = input("Enter text to encrypt: ")
distance = int(input("Enter number of offset: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    distance %= 56
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance -(ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
    code = code + chr(cipherValue)
print("distance= ",distance)
print(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be totally clear on what you want, but IMHO you're not wrapping correctly. Is this what you're trying to do? (It does work with the examples you provided.)

```
plainText = input("Enter text to encrypt: ")
distance = int(input("Enter number of offset: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = (ordValue + distance) % 128
    code = code + chr(cipherValue)
print("distance= ",distance)
print(code)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Im not too sure on why that made such a large difference but that worked.